# No module named backends.default.urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

So I've installed django-registration through easy_install. I'm following a quick start guide and I'm trying to setup my urlConf, however it says module named backends.defauls.urls is not found. What might be the problem ?

```
import registration
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

Comment: I think this is happening because you are following the documentation for a later version than you have. registration.backends.default.urls is going to be deprecated in version 0.9 and then removed. Could you have a version in which registration.urls is still correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the registration module in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: It is. Problem solved, I had to use include('registration.urls'), why does the docs say I should use include('registration.backends.default.urls') when it doesn't work..

Answer (score 27):

(not my solution, but since it was hidden in a comment)

You need to use use `include('registration.urls')`,

instead of `include('registration.backends.default.urls')`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest always getting django-registration from Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/overview.

I had a similar problem where I installed django-registration using pip install and it wasn't giving me up-to-date code.

Comment: Agreed, grab from bitbucket to get latest, but the docs are still incorrect - @Marijius has the correct include statement that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Apparently the server where I'm trying to upload the urls.py script has an older version, 0.7 I think.

My initial workaround was to put django-registration as an app (from the source) and include it in INSTALLED_APPS, with the registration folder right alongside my other apps.

Then the new problem was that the installed version is being looked up before the 'custom' app, especially on imports. For example, in views.py, we have an

```
from registration.backends import get_backend
```

which seems to be missing from the 0.7 version. So this raises an exception, but checking on the registration app the function is there in registration/backend/**init**.py.

This causes clashes between the custom registration app (0.8) and the one installed server-wide (0.7) that I can't seem to get around to.