# No module named backends.simple.urls

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm having a similar problem that is stated in this question: [No module named backends.default.urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259497/no-module-named-backends-default-urls)
However, I'm trying to use the simple backend, so just doing `include('registration.backends.simple.urls')` doesn't quite cut it for me.

Does anyone know how I could make the django-registration work with simple backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer:
I installed django-registration via `django-registration==0.7` in my requirements.txt file
I instead used the most up-to-date version of django-registration (0.8) by replacing that very line in my requirements with `hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration`.

Alternatively, you just call `pip install hg+https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration`

Answer (score 1):

This  should work:

```
include('registration.backends.simple.urls')
```

It is consistent with [the actual urls module](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/registration/backends/simple/urls.py). If it doesn't work, upgrade to bitbucket version.