# Django 1.5, django-registration 1.0: "No module named backends.default.urls"

Tags: django, django-registration

I am: Django 1.5, django-registration 1.0; DEV environ is windows and PROD environ is an EC2 instance with Ubuntu12.4.

I am getting the error: **No module named backends.default.urls** in both PROD and DEV environs.  However, in DEV, the one time it works fine is when I:

> put django-registration as an app (from the source) and include it in
>   INSTALLED_APPS, with the registration folder right alongside my other
>   apps.

Any idea why it works fine in DEV and not in PROD?

Also, if I **instead** use:

> pip install django-registration

and follow the suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7349220/3254791 I get the error **No module named urls** instead of **No module named backends.default.urls**

Answer (score 0):

you likely have an old *.pyc file lying around from django 1.4 which is making it work in DEV

Comment: Problem is now gone.  When I recreated the database in PROD it worked.  Not sure if that was the problem.  It could have been other URL configurations regarding admin too.  How do I close this thread?